# How can I have an axis label automatically positioned below the X-axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I'm attempting to generate some histograms, and I'd like to automatically label the X-axis.  `However, Histogram[. . ., AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]` places the "X" label on the RHS of the axis.  How do I direct that the "X" label should be positioned below the axis?  I need some automated method (I can of course move it by hand), since I'm going to be generating hundreds of diagrams.

Comment: Related question:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17902/how-to-place-legend-labels-for-histogram-and-listlineplots-correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Frame->True`

```
Histogram[{1, 2, 3}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Y", None}, {"X", "my histogram"}}, 
  RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I wish there was a way of doing it without the frame

Answer (score 4):

> *I wish there was a way of doing it without the frame* - Karolis

```
Labeled[Histogram[{1, 2, 3}], {"X", "Y"}, {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]