# Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes

Tags: plotting, labeling

By default Mathematica places the x-axis labels at the end of the axes like[image]

Googling has suggested a way around this is to use `Frame`- for example `Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> {"E/T", None}` which produces something like [image]

Which is not too bad, but I do not want this vertical dividing line `x=0` and really would have preffered to keep the `y-axis` in the middle of the plot where this divider line now is. Can this be done? Is there a better way than this to move axes labels below?

Comment: Question is related [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17303/how-can-i-have-an-axis-label-automatically-positioned-below-the-x-axis)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Which is not too bad, but I do not want this vertical dividing line $x = 0$ and really would have preferred to keep the $y$-axis in the middle of the plot where this divider line now is.

An easy way is to use `Labeled` with `Plot` since `Plot` keeps the y axis in the middle while `Frame->True` moves it to the left where you do not want it.

```
Labeled[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3}], "E/T"]
```

[image]

`Labeled` has [many option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Labeled.html) to allow different placements and alignments and such, so it can actually be used instead of the plot labeling. The only thing to keep in mind, is that symbols used in inside the Plot, such as those used by `PlotLabel` are automatically set in `TraditionalMode` while those set by `Labeled` are not and you have to do that yourself if you want that typesetting. Compare the typesetting below on the labels:

```
Grid[{

  {Labeled[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 300],Sin[x]]},

  {Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3},AxesLabel->{Sin[x],None},ImageSize->300]}

 }, Frame -> All
]
```

[image]

But this is easy to handle. Simply use `TraditionalForm` for `Labeled, like this

```
Clear[x];

Labeled[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 300], 

 Text@TraditionalForm@Style[Sin[x], 16]

]
```

[image]

**edit**
To answer the comment about exporting;

I just saved the image using `Save Selection` as eps, and labels are there

[image]

I am on Linux, and `Export` in the version of Mahematica I am using is not supported. But it seems to save .eps just fine.

Comment: thanks, that works pretty well. I didn't mention in my OP but I actually have three plots that I usually show on the same axis using `Show[plot1,plot2,plot3]` -with your method if I do `Show[ Labeled[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3}], "E/T"],Labeled[Plot[Cos[x] x, {x, -3, 3}], "E/T"]]` for example then things don't seem to work.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Actually I see now that `Labeled[Show[plot1, plot2, plot3], "E/T", 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[20, Bold]]` works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: If one then exports this figure as an `eps` say the axes labels do not seem to get exported too?

Comment: Sorry my mistake again- the problem was I was simply doing `Right-click>Export' rather than the command version which gave the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 26):

```
  Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"E/T", None}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the axis now sits away from (-3,0) by a small margin. Do you know how to set it exactly at (-3,0)?

Comment: @Corvus, you can use the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0`.

Comment: You're amazing - answering a two year old post in under 5 minutes - thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled) can be suboptimal because the location of the label along the horizontal axis can only be set to [`Left`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Left), [`Center`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Center) or [`Right`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Right). If the vertical axis ticks are large, then none of these positions is truly satisfactory. For instance:

```
bar = BarChart[Range[4], BarOrigin->Left, ChartLabels->{aaaaaaaaaaaaa, b, c, d}];
Labeled[
    bar,
    "x-axis",
    {{Bottom, Center}}
]
```

[image]

One might wish to place the "x-axis" label centered at ~2.1 instead of ~1.6.

Using [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel) instead is a possibility, but sometimes (as in this question), the axes origin does not coincide with the lower left corner.

So, below I will present 3 other possibilities. All of these approaches need to gather some information about the plot using the function `GraphicsInformation`, a function given in my answer to [Retrieving the ImagePadding in absolute units](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2091/45431). This function is now a paclet, and can be installed and loaded with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];

<<GraphicsInformation`
```

**Ticks**

The first option is to include the label using the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks) option. To do this we first need to obtain the ticks using [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions) *(I need to change the plot range because [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions) doesn't like the default [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) for [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart))*:

```
ticks = OptionValue[
    AbsoluteOptions[Show[bar, PlotRange->OptionValue[GraphicsInformation[bar], "PlotRange"]]],
    Ticks
];
```

To add a label centered at `2.1`, we just prepend a tick:

```
newticks = Replace[ticks, {a_, b_} :> {Prepend[a, {2.1, Underscript["", Style["x-axis", 14]], 0}], b}];
Show[bar, Ticks -> newticks]
```

[image]

The downside to this approach is the need to figure out the ticks, and you will notice that the ticks returned by AbsoluteTicks use decimals.

**Epilog**

The second option is to use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog) and adjust the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding). To do this we first need to find the old [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding):

```
old = OptionValue[GraphicsInformation[bar], "ImagePadding"]
```

> {{68.1939, 1.5}, {13.4116, 2.84217*10^-14}}

Then, we place the "x-axis" label using a [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) directive in an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog):

```
Show[
    bar,
    Epilog->Text[Style["x-axis", 14], Offset[{0, -15}, {2.1, 0}], {0, 1}],
    ImagePadding -> old + {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}
]
```

[image]

The `Offset[{0, -15}, {2.1, 0}]` argument places the label at the position `{2.1, 0}` in plot coordinates, then moves the label lower by 15 points. The [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) is adjusted so that the label is included in the plot. The downside to this approach is that the option `PlotRangeClipping->False` must be used, otherwise the epilog will not be displayed.

**Inset**

The final option is to use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset) to place the plot inside of a graphics object that can contain other elements (like an x-axis label). With this approach, we don't need to worry about the [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping) option. To do this, we will need to know some information about the bar chart using GraphicsInformation. One needed tweak is to set the axes origin back to `{0,0}`:

```
{pad, size, pr, prsize} = OptionValue[
    GraphicsInformation[Show[bar, AxesOrigin->{0, 0}]],
    {"ImagePadding", "ImageSize", "PlotRange", "PlotRangeSize"}
];
```

The above information can be used to create the following [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object:

```
Graphics[
    {
    Inset[
        Show[bar, ImagePadding->pad, AxesOrigin->{0, 0}],
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        Offset[size]
    ],
    Text[Style["x-axis", 14], Offset[{0, -15}, {2.1, 0}], {0, 1}]
    },
    PlotRange->pr,
    ImagePadding->pad + {{0, 0}, {10, 0}},
    ImageSize->Automatic->prsize
]
```

[image]

The [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) option in the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset) shouldn't be necessary, but unfortunately there appears to be a bug in `GraphicsInformation`.