# How to set the position of the axis label in program?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, text, frame

I have studied the relational contents through the webpage [Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/placing-x-axes-label-below-rather-than-at-end-of-axes), but not found: (1)How to put annotation on the left of y axis and display the graphic properly without using `FrameLabel`. I don't use the function `FrameLabel` because the curve owns value in the positive and negative y axis. I found if using `FrameLabel`, the x-direction frame will display on the bottom **without overlapping x axis**. (2)The webpage **didn't point out how to adjust the distance** between the text generated from `FrameLabel` and axis. The default distance between `FrameLabel` text such as text "x-axis" in the following picture and x axis is very far, so it can not be used in paper directly. So I think it necessary to open a new post here.

In the first row of the following picture, I want to insert an annotation "y-label text" into fig 1-a and make it become into the fig 1-b; the second, move a little bit of "x-axis" and "y-axis" to their axis in the fig 2-a and make it into the fig 2-b. The codes and pictures as follows. How can I achieve the results? Thank you!

For fig 1-a

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

For fig 2-a

```
Plot[x^2 + 4, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y-axis", None}, {"x-axis", None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

and the picture:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/placing-x-axes-label-below-rather-than-at-end-of-axes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach: add the labels in desired places using `Epilog` (with the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and the option setting for `ImagePadding`  large enough to avoid cropping of the labels):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"x", None}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
 Epilog -> Text[Style[Rotate["y-label text", 90 Degree], Red, Bold], {-.5, .5}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x^2 + 4, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameTicks -> All, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.1], Automatic}, {Scaled[.1], Automatic}},
  Epilog -> {Text["y axis", {-.25, 17.5}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}], 
    Text["x axis", {2.5, 1.5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for hitting the key of the problem. Can you insert a comma at the end of the sentence `ImagePadding`?  In case others may refer to the codes.

Comment: @likehust, thank you. Fixed the missing comma.