# How to place legend labels for Histogram and ListLinePlots correctly?

Tags: plotting

I would like to place AxesLabels:

1. For x axis at center of the Histogram and LineListPLots.
2. For y axis rotated 90 degree anti clockwise.

I don't see any options for it?

```
Histogram[Table[zcb[i],{i,mcRunHJM}],AxesLabel->{Price,Relative Frequency}]

ListLinePlot[Table[zcb[i],{i,mcRunHJM}],PlotRange->{{0,mcRunHJM},{0.9,1.1}}, PlotLabel->Style["Convergence",FontSize->12],AxesLabel->{Simulation Step,Price}]
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `FrameLabel`.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17303/how-can-i-have-an-axis-label-automatically-positioned-below-the-x-axis)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the histogram:

```
Labeled[Histogram[
  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]], {Rotate[
   "Relative Frequency", 90 Degree], "Price"}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Further to Sebastian's comment to add stats:-

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Labeled[Histogram[data,
  Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Grid[{
       {"Mean =", Mean[data]},
       {"Max =", Max[data]},
       {"Min =", Min[data]}},
      Alignment -> {{Left}}], Background -> White],
    {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}],
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier"}], {Rotate[
   "Relative Frequency", 90 Degree], "Price"},
 {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

To show two data sets, two methods:-

```
dataA = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
dataB = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];

Labeled[Histogram[{dataA, dataB},
  ChartStyle -> {ColorData[3, 4], ColorData[3, 6]},
  ChartLegends -> {
    Style[StringJoin["Set A mean = ",
      ToString[Round[Mean[dataA], 10.^-6]]],
     FontFamily -> "Courier"],
    Style[StringJoin["Set B mean = ",
      ToString[Round[Mean[dataB], 10.^-6]]],
     FontFamily -> "Courier"]}],
 {Rotate["Relative Frequency", 90 Degree],
  "Price                         "}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

For more control of appearance the second method uses `ShowLegend`:-

```
(* Specify common bin division size *)
histA = Histogram[dataA, {0.5}];
histB = Histogram[dataB, {0.5}];
(* Find common plot range and axes origin *)
minmaxA = First[PlotRange /. Options[histA, PlotRange]];
minmaxB = First[PlotRange /. Options[histB, PlotRange]];
tAB = Transpose[{minmaxA, minmaxB}];
minmaxAB = {Min[First[tAB]], Max[Last[tAB]]};
aoA = First[AxesOrigin /. Options[histA, AxesOrigin]];
aoB = First[AxesOrigin /. Options[histB, AxesOrigin]];
aoAB = Min[aoA, aoB];

Quiet[Needs["PlotLegends`"]];
Labeled[
 ShowLegend[Show[
   Histogram[dataA, {0.5},
    ChartBaseStyle -> {ColorData[3, 4], Opacity[0.5]}],
   Histogram[dataB, {0.5},
    ChartBaseStyle -> {ColorData[3, 6], Opacity[0.5]}],
   PlotRange -> {minmaxAB, {All, All}},
   AxesOrigin -> {aoAB, 0}],

  {{{Graphics[{ColorData[3, 4], Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[]}], 
     Style[StringJoin["Set A mean = ",
       ToString[Round[Mean[dataA], 10.^-6]]],
      FontFamily -> "Courier"]}, {Graphics[{ColorData[3, 6], 
       Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[]}], Style[StringJoin["Set B mean = ",
       ToString[Round[Mean[dataB], 10.^-6]]],
      FontFamily -> "Courier"]}},
   LegendPosition -> {0.2, 0.6},
   LegendSize -> {1.1, 0.25},
   LegendTextSpace -> 8,
   LegendShadow -> None}],
 {Rotate["Relative Frequency", 90 Degree], "Price      "},
 {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

And a matching `ListLinePlot`:-

```
linedataA = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 20];
linedataB = Accumulate[linedataA];

ListLinePlot[{linedataA, linedataB},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel ->
   Map[Style[#, {FontFamily -> "Courier", 13}] &,
   {"Simulation Step", "Price"}],
 PlotLegends -> {"Set A", "Set B"}]
```

[image]

You might find this book useful: [Mathematica Navigator](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=7352).  It shows a lot of charting techniques.

Comment: Hi Chris, what about placing the Mean[List], Max[List] and Min[List] on the histogram (or ListLinePlot) that I already calculated? At the moment they are simply outputs somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Chris, could you show how to overlay histogram simulations a and b together? I tried plot1=Labeled[Histogram[data...]], plot2=Labeled[Histogram[data...]], and then Show[plot1, plot2] doesnt work? Error:Labeled is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks very cool, but not sure the difference between the two from the histograms? Dont see where you define the histogram colors and thickness? By ColorData?

Comment: ChartLegends is not an option for ListLinePlot? Tried applying the Histogram example for ListLinePlot but returns->  Unknown option ChartLegends?

Comment: @sebastian c. - For `ListPlot` you can use `PlotLegends` (as shown), or `ShowLegend`, as shown earlier.

Answer (score 12):

This can be accomplished by a combination of two options: `Frame` and `FrameLabel`.

```
data = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
ListPlot[data, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

As shown above, `FrameLabels` by itself does not do it as you need to specify which sides of the frame are displayed. Note, this applies to all two dimensional plots.

Comment: Thanks @rcollyer, though the FrameLabel looks small, any way set FontSize? But applying it on the Histogram I noticed the whole set of data gets shifted up so data seems to be floating instead of where it was before?       Histogram[Table[zcb[i],{i,mcRunHJM}],FrameLabel-> {"Price","Relative Frequency"},Frame-> {True, True, False, False}]

Comment: @sebastianc. [`LabelStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LabelStyle.html). Also, if this is useful to you, you should vote for it. If it solves your problem, you should accept it. I'd suggest accepting only after a period of time (like 24 hours) to allow for other answers to come in.

Comment: @BrettChampion both forms work, at least in 8.

Comment: Yes, both forms work, but I'd rather people learn to use the "new" (introduced in V6) syntax rather than the older syntax.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the frame method for histograms as well as for plots. To stop it shifting up the you can set `PlotRangePadding` to `None` for the relevant side. In addition, if manually setting the chart range, you can turn off the y-axis to avoid a nasty line in your histogram marking the first bin. Finally, I change the font settings using `BaseStyle`.

```
Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200],
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
  FrameLabel -> {"Price", "Frequency"},
  PlotRangePadding->{Automatic, {None, Automatic}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, Automatic}, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

Produces:

[image: Histogram with sensible axis label positions]