# How to label the axes without keeping the frame?

Tags: labeling, code-request, frame

I have this plot

[image]

And I shall label the axes as if I were in the Frame ambient that is, putting $t$ and $d\psi/dt$ on the axis but not at their top and right (like in the normal `AxesLabel` mode) but in the `FrameLabel` mode.

The problem is that I don't want any frame.

I don't know if I have been clear, but it's like to be able to write $t$ above the `X` axis, like in the middle, and $d\psi/dt$ at the left of the `Y` axis, in the middle.

Thank you!

Comment: related/possible duplicate Q/As: [Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17747/125), [How can I have an axis label automatically positioned below the X-axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17303/125), [How to place legend labels for Histogram and ListLinePlots correctly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17902/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Plot[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 Epilog -> {
   Inset[Style["t", 12], {10, -1.5}],
   Inset[Style[Rotate["dw/dt", Pi/2], 12], {-2, 3}]},
 PlotRangePadding -> 2.5]
```

[image]

**Update**

Probably a better solution is:

```
Plot[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["dw/dt", 12], None}, {Style["t", 12], None}},
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! What if I wanted a Cartesian Plane without the X and Y negative parts? Shall I use something like "axesOrigin"?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Just one more question, sorry for bothering you: what about that little gap in the second plot? Is there a way to remove it? >.<

Comment: I don't see an easy way to remove the gap - unless you want to write your own axis-function

Comment: @HenryTuring Maybe add `PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 4}}`

Comment: or even `PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}`

Comment: @george2079 PlotRangePadding -> None works perfect!

Comment: Thanks for the comments - now without the gap