# How to put x-Label below the x-Axis?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How to put label "*Iterations*" below x-axis? Possibly in an easy way without multiple commands.

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2};
b = {3, 2, 5, 6, 9};
c = {2, 7, 3, 1, 6};
d = {4, 2, 8, 8, 10};
am = {Position[a, Max[a]][[1, 1]], Max[a]}
bm = {Position[b, Max[b]][[1, 1]], Max[b]}
cm = {Position[c, Max[c]][[1, 1]], Max[c]}
dm = {Position[d, Max[d]][[1, 1]], Max[d]}
ListLinePlot[{a, b, c, d}, AxesLabel -> {"Iteraciones", "Objetivo"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Orange}, {Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.01]}, {Thickness[0.01], Dashed, Red}}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Point[{am, bm, cm, dm}]}]
```

Comment: Would you be happy to use a framed plot? Then modding to `Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Iteraciones", "Objetivo"}` does the trick already.

Comment: Without `Frame` you can use `Labeled[(*plot*),"Iteraciones", Bottom]`

Comment: @kuba SOLVED. Thank You

Comment: @YvesKlett SOLVED. Thank you.

Comment: When you type "label plot below" you will get a first link to: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17747/5478 so next time  please try to look for the answer via search engine in top right corner first :)

Comment: do you know what Font is the default for graphs?... to use the same in the Labeled X-axis

Comment: The difference is probably with that Labels inside Graphics are in TraditionalForm. p.s. another [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17303/5478)

Comment: @kuba , I saw that post before, but It don´t help me because... what I want is modify ONLY the x-label, and CONTINUE MAINTAINING the Y-bale over the Y label. To have the minimun possible width. Finally my solution with your help is http://sensa.square7.ch/gfdgdf51.jpg  The only thing I would like to add,... is use the same Font in the bottom Label as the other label and numbers-marks

Comment: I think that this question may be usefull to minimize the width of a graph.

Comment: Voting to close because it is a duplicate of the first question @Kuba suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I prefer `Frame->True` for most of my plots.

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2};
b = {3, 2, 5, 6, 9};
c = {2, 7, 3, 1, 6};
d = {4, 2, 8, 8, 10};
max = {Position[#, Max[#]][[1, 1]], Max[#]} & /@ {a, b, c, d};
ListLinePlot[{a, b, c, d}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Iteraciones", Red, Large], 
   Style["Objetivo", Blue, Small]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Orange}, {Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.01]}, {Thickness[0.01], Dashed, Red}}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Point[max]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

This is just a modification of Yves' answer. If you really don't want a framed look, you can expand out the option value of the `Framed` option to address each side individually, like this:

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2};
b = {3, 2, 5, 6, 9};
c = {2, 7, 3, 1, 6};
d = {4, 2, 8, 8, 10};
max = {Position[#, Max[#]][[1, 1]], Max[#]} & /@ {a, b, c, d};
ListLinePlot[{a, b, c, d}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.2, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Iteraciones", Red, Large], 
   Style["Objetivo", Blue, Small]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Orange}, {Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.01]}, {Thickness[0.01], Dashed, Red}}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Point[max]}]
```

[image]

Notice that I have also added some `PlotRangePadding` to avoid the big dots being cut off.

Comment: And here was I thinking that this was such a trivial addition to Yves' answer that I should CW it. Three up votes in an hour?

Comment: Well, it *is* a useful addition :D